# togglewidth jquery not working with percentages?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle the width of a div based on percentages, however it's not working, it works perfectly fine with pixels.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#toggle-button').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#toggle").width() == 100 ? "100%" : "50%";
        $('#toggle').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7z8n4bu5/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `width()` returns numeric pixel value, not percentage. If you want to know percentage you need to calculate it yourself

Comment: What should the 100% and 50% refer to, the width of the browser or the width you originally set? Also, please post a [mcve] in your question, not on jsFiddle